# Android player WOWZA server RTSP stream issue

Tags: android, streaming, video-streaming, android-videoview, wowza

I am streaming rtsp stream from wowza server. My android player is ending up is error many times. I am getting error after playing few seconds or minutes.

Here is the error log:

```
05-26 15:47:27.339: WARN/NEXTREAMING(1458): ERR0:2167 _iConfigLen 0,  pVDI-     >ebdq.nFilled 0
05-26 15:47:27.339: ERROR/QCvdec(1458): Omx Flush issued when vdec is not initialized yet.
05-26 15:47:27.339: ERROR/(1458): Flush VDL_stats_q: stats_ptr 0x27d88
05-26 15:47:27.339: ERROR/QCvdec(1458): Warning - previous ts > current ts. And both are non B-frames
05-26 15:47:27.349: WARN/NEXTREAMING(1458): ERR0:[Video 870] ==> Decoding failure. (0), CTS(263960)
05-26 15:47:27.349: WARN/NEXTREAMING(1458): ERR0:[Video 873] FIRE_ONERROR [NEXPLAYER_ERROR_CODEC]
05-26 15:47:27.349: WARN/NEXTREAMING(1458): ERR0:[VideoDecTask 874] Error(0xe)   Occurred! Stop[0], Async[2147483647]
05-26 15:47:27.349: WARN/NEXTREAMING(1458): ERR0:[CommonEvnets670] SEND   MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN : NEXPLAYER_EVENT_ERROR(Error Code:0x0000000e)
05-26 15:47:27.349: ERROR/MediaPlayer(4923): error (1, 0)
05-26 15:47:27.359: ERROR/MediaPlayer(4923): <!>android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler 1340<!> Error (1,0)
05-26 15:47:27.359: DEBUG/VideoView(4923): <!>android.widget.VideoView$4 357<!> Error: 1,0
05-26 15:47:27.419: ERROR/QCvdec(1458): Omx Flush issued when vdec is not initialized yet.
05-26 15:47:27.419: ERROR/(1458): Flush VDL_stats_q: stats_ptr 0x0
05-26 15:47:27.429: WARN/QCvdec(1458):     ======================================================================
05-26 15:47:27.429: WARN/QCvdec(1458):                    Open Max   Statistics                                
05-26 15:47:27.429: WARN/QCvdec(1458):    ======================================================================
05-26 15:47:27.429: WARN/QCvdec(1458): empty this buffer rate = 11.547641
05-26 15:47:27.429: WARN/QCvdec(1458): empty this buffer total time = 28490667
05-26 15:47:27.429: WARN/QCvdec(1458): empty this buffer count = 329
05-26 15:47:27.429: WARN/QCvdec(1458): ======================================================================
05-26 15:47:27.429: WARN/(1458): ===========================================================
05-26 15:47:27.429: WARN/(1458):                      Arm  Statistics                        
05-26 15:47:27.429: WARN/(1458): ===========================================================
05-26 15:47:27.429: WARN/(1458): Total number of frames decoded = 322
05-26 15:47:27.429: WARN/(1458): Average Arm time/frame(ms)     = 0.488919
05-26 15:47:27.429: WARN/(1458): Frames Arm Decoded/sec         = 2045.327515
05-26 15:47:27.429: WARN/(1458): ===========================================================
05-26 15:47:27.429: WARN/(1458):                     Frame Done  Statistics                  
05-26 15:47:27.429: WARN/(1458):  ===========================================================
05-26 15:47:27.429: WARN/(1458): Frame done cumulative time     = 31283552
05-26 15:47:27.429: WARN/(1458): Frames Done per second         = 10.260983
05-26 15:47:27.429: WARN/(1458):   ===========================================================
05-26 15:47:27.439: WARN/(1458): ===========================================================
05-26 15:47:27.439: WARN/(1458):                       Dsp Statistics                       
05-26 15:47:27.439: WARN/(1458): ===========================================================
05-26 15:47:27.439: WARN/(1458): Total number of frames decoded = 322
05-26 15:47:27.439: WARN/(1458): Average Dsp time/frame(ms)     = 14.353993
05-26 15:47:27.439: WARN/(1458): Frames Dsp Decoded/sec)        = 69.667023
05-26 15:47:27.439: WARN/(1458): ===========================================================
```

Please help me in fixing this issue

Answer (score 2):

From the error it looks like the stream that wowza is producing for you cannot be decoded by the OMX decoder on phone you are testing. Try changing settings with wowza.  You can check wowza sample stream: rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_175k.mov

If that works then your wowza settings are probably wrong.

Kind regards,
Bo